# Plotting weekly data with calculations

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to create a graph using the following sample data:

df:

```
  ID       DAY  STORE PRODid QTY   GBP    PROD
2 8042899 1584 70470 1372     6    9.54  Yogurt
3 8042899 1586 70470 1372     2    3.18  Yogurt
4 8042899 1589 70470 1372     2    3.18  Yogurt
5 8042899 1590 70470  307     3    3.27  Yogurt
6 8042899 1590 70470  300     2    2.18  Yogurt
7 8042899 1590 70470 1372     1    1.59  Yogurt
```

I am running into an error here;

```
 df[, .(total_sales = (sum(QTY) * (GBP))), by = DAY]
ggplot(aes(x = total_sales)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = 'steelblue', bins = 50) +
  labs(x = 'Day unit sales', title = 'Titlte of plot')
```

Is the problem with the `DAY` column not being a `ts` object?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @PoGibas Good remark: I would even say a timeseries plot, not at all histogram or barplot (considered the remark on `ts` object)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you actually want to plot, nor do you say what the error is that you encounter; I assume you want to plot `total_sales` as a function of `DAY`. As suggested by @PoGibas, you can do that using `geom_bar`:

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "  ID       DAY  STORE PRODid QTY   GBP    PROD
2 8042899 1584 70470 1372     6    9.54  Yogurt
3 8042899 1586 70470 1372     2    3.18  Yogurt
4 8042899 1589 70470 1372     2    3.18  Yogurt
5 8042899 1590 70470  307     3    3.27  Yogurt
6 8042899 1590 70470  300     2    2.18  Yogurt
7 8042899 1590 70470 1372     1    1.59  Yogurt", header = T)

require(data.table);
require(margrittr);
require(ggplot2);

df <- as.data.table(df);

df[, .(total_sales = (sum(QTY) * (GBP))), by = DAY] %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = DAY, y = total_sales)) +
   geom_bar(fill = 'steelblue', stat = "identity") +
    labs(x = 'Day', title = 'Title of plot')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! one last question; I am trying to use the pipe function instead of ";" but when I try to modify your code and use the pipe function %>% I get errors.

Comment: @user113156 I've edited my answer to use `magrittr`s pipe operator; please take a look.